# Solr configuration replication

Tags: solr, replication, master-slave

In order to change configuration on slaves I want to change configuration on master simply by editing solrconf.xml file. What should I do in order to trigger pulls on slaves or it will happen automatically since file modification date was changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Solr replication to send the configuration files (schema.xml & solrconfig.xml) as well as other configuration files (stopwords.txt, synonyms.txt, etc.). See the [Solr Replication - How are configuration files replicated?](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_are_configuration_files_replicated.3F) section on the Solr wiki for details and notes on how this works.

Here is the replication configuration section from the [solrconfig.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml?view=markup) example that comes with Solr 3.6.1. Please note the `confFiles` entry.

```
 <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
   <lst name="master">
     <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
     <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
     <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
   </lst>
   <lst name="slave">
     <str name="masterUrl">http://localhost:8983/solr/replication</str>
     <str name="pollInterval">00:00:60</str>
   </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```